# Difference between apple developer and enterprise account

Tags: ios, app-store, iosdeployment

We use apple developer account for submit IOS application in appStore. we got this email from apple after 10 days :

We are unable to include your app, **MY APPLICATION**, on the App Store. Under the U.S. sanctions regulations, the App Store cannot host, distribute, or do business with apps or developers connected to certain U.S. embargoed countries.

This area of law is complex and constantly changing. If the existing restrictions shift, we encourage you to resubmit your app for inclusion on the App Store.

our company in Iran and apple reject our request for Political reason. 
now we want to publish application with enterprise account, my question is with enterprise account we should have get appStore review? that means We will rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise account mean it should be used within your company, the app signed by that will be able to install to any devices, as long as the user trust the account in device management, it cannot be use to publish on AppStore.

You can anyway, host it in your website and ask people to download from there and trust the company without needing approval from Apple

Answer (score 0):

**A good advise for you (your company), establish a small branch outside Iran (where, there is no any kind of restriction) and register for developer account from new location.



OR

 Your company can create Individual account by using trustable resource of organization living outside Iran (with citizenship of other county).**

Enterprise account is for enterprise (in house) applications only. Enterprise account is useful, If you want to distribute your application to specific segment of users, to whom you can share IPA build directly using downloable source (server).

You can find official information about apple enterprise account from this link: 

[Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/)

But if want to distribute your app for general public usage, which is not limited to specific segment of users, you should use/choose [Individuals or Organisation (Non-Enterprise) Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)

Here you can see difference between enterprise & developer account:

[Choosing a Membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

Comment: our developer account for company in Dubai not Iran. But Apple understands the Iranian appleHow does this happen? I do not know.

Comment: You are right, as per my point of view, Apple is doing wrong. But they can't fight against US government for the same. As it's their native place for business.

Comment: Try to upload build from other geographic location (using remote access from remote computer)

Answer (score 0):

**AppStore :**
With AppStore account you need to distribute application through iTunes and it will go through iOS review guidelines and It should satisfy those guidelines.

**Enterprise :**
With Enterprise account you will still be able to work exactly like how you process for app development. But, Under enterprise account you will not be asked for application review.
Using Enterprise account you will be generating InHouse certificates and provisioning profiles and using it you can distribute your app within your organization and you will not get portal to download app like AppStore.
You need to create or expose link from there user can download app.

Your app .plist should be included with link or path where the .ipa is stored. 
You can deploy your app at any time without apple review process.